# Will I still receive push notifications if I remove an app?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

If I download an app on my iPhone and it automatically appears on my iPad and I delete it from my iPad that means no notifications should pop up on my iPad anymore because I deleted it - even if I use it on my iPhone, correct?

Answer (score 3):

That is **correct**—the device won't be delivered notifications if you remove the app.

Comment: Fish for a man and he'll eat one day. Learn a man to fish...

Comment: I was just wondering because I donwloaded an app on my phone - a way to send text messages and it popped up on my ipad and I didn't want app on my ipad so now if someone messaged me on my iphone it shouldn't pop up on my ipad because I already deleted the app - so that's good!

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Only the device where the app is installed will receive the updates.